# Bloomberg =baddperiods() and =bdh() issue

Tags: excel, terminal, bloomberg

I'm on my research project to find the last price for a security at IPO and 20 trading days after for 5 years. I use =BDP($A$1, "EQY_INIT_PO_DT") to get the IPO trading date and its fine. The issue happened when I use =BADDPERIODS(A2, "NumberOfPeriods", "20", "CDR", "ID JA", "BusDayAdj", "1") it still include the non trading days. So when I use =BDH($A$1, "PX_LAST", A6, A6) it shows #N/A N/A. I guess =baddperiods() function outputted the non trading days and the =bdh() unable to get the price. How can I obtain the correct 20 trading days (exclude weekends and any public / non-trading days) after a certain date?

```
Reference:
A1= Company Ticker
A2= IPO Date
A3= =BADDPERIODS(A2, "NumberOfPeriods", "20", "CDR", "ID JA", "BusDayAdj", "1")
...
A6= =BADDPERIODS(A5, "NumberOfPeriods", "20", "CDR", "ID JA", "BusDayAdj", "1")
```

[image: Excel]
[image: Bloomberg Historical Prices]

Comment: From the Bloomberg menu choose the Function Builder. BDH() has a lot of options for choosing a calendar, and what to do with missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BDH() worksheet function has optional parameters that specify how the timeseries data is returned. These come after the start and end date parameters. One of these allows a calendar to be specified. Specifying a calendar prompts Bloomberg to look back and find the closest (but earlier) 'good' value for the date requested.

The short, but inefficient answer is to use this formula in cell B6:

```
=BDH($A$1,"PX_LAST",A6,A6,"CDR","JA")
```

[image]

It is inefficient because each cell is making a relatively expensive call to Bloomberg for one day's history. It is better to pull back all the history from the start date to today in a single call, and put it in some spare columns. Then look your date up (using INDEX/MATCH) to find the price value.

Comment: WOW It worked! Thanks a lot. For the A column, it's still =baddperiods right? And for the B column, it takes the last price before holiday?

Comment: @jasferdian Yes, your addperiods is fine. The missing data is not because of holidays, it is the lack of price from the exchange, because no-one bought or sold the security on that day: as you can see from the Bloomberg screenshot in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the previous help. But at some data, I still got #N/A N/A error :( can you help me on "BAPA IJ Equity" with the date of 5/9/2016 6/6/2016 7/11/2016. With the formula =BDH($B$242,"PX_last",L27,L27,"CDR","JA")

B242 = BAPA IJ Equity

Comment: IDK whats wrong with those dates, what can I add in the =bdh() formula to take the latest price :(

Comment: @jasferdian What is wrong with 'those dates' is that the illiquid stock did not trade, so there is no PX_LAST. Look on HP on the Terminal: you will see blanks. You can try adding "FILL","C" as an extra option. Otherwise Help Help on your Bloomberg Terminal. There are people at Bloomberg who are actually paid to answer these questions! ;-) Another approach (albeit again inefficient) is: `=INDEX(BDH($B$242,"PX_LAST",L27-30,L277,"CDR","JA","FILL","C","SORT","R","ARRAY","TRUE"),1,2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! It solved some #N/A issue. Sorry for my lack of knowledge of Bloomberg function. I'll try to reach out Bloomberg representative to help me cause I need it urgently rn :). Hope to learn more from you! @DS_London